# Writing small files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I know it sound silly and understand hadoop is not meant for small files but unfortunately i have received 6000+ small files each of around 50kb.

Everytime i try to run "hadoop fs -put -f /path/FOLDER_WITH_FILES /target/HDSF_FOLDER" it always fails for one the random file while making connection with namenode.

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 75000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel
```

I was wondering if there any better approach to write small in HDFS.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the exact command and the error message.

Comment: @philantrovert added exception.

Answer (score 0):

It is always advisable to merge all your small files into hadoop sequence file, and process it.
It will give you performance gain.

Comment: Or Bzip2 file since that format can be created by 7zip, for example, more easily

Comment: Thanks . Do you suggest to unzip Bzip2 again in HDFS ?

Comment: @Shashi - No. Hadoop can natively process files within the archive within MapReduce and other frameworks